# How to implement Transaction Manager for multiple Dao

Tags: java, model-view-controller, transactions, transactionmanager

I am writing a Java application following the MVC pattern, abstract enough to allow the backend to connect to an Sql and a NoSql database. I have 4 model classes and 4 DAO interfaces. Each DAO is implemented in two ways, one for sql and one for mongodb. I want to add a Transaction Manager to execute database operations in atomic transactions: the problem is that these operations involve a variable number of DAOs and I don't know how to implement the Manager with more than one Dao. **I'm not using Spring and I'm not willing to add it.**

I've had the following ideas but each one has something I'm not sure about:

- Make interfaces `MyDao_X` extend another interface `GenericDao` and use the last one in TransactionCode. This way I wouldn't know which Dao to instantiate in `TransactionManagerMysql`
- Extend Function to be an N-Function which can accept N inputs and produce an output. In this case N = 4, so I could always instantiate all the DAOs. Here the doubts are the following: I don't know how to do and I'm following TDD so I should figure out how to test this extension. Moreover, it doesn't seem very efficient to me to instantiate 4 Dao every time just because I don't know how many or the type I need. Additionally, if the number of Dao changes over time, I would be forced to modify all the functions in Service Layer to adapt the number of inputs to lambdas

## What I would do if I had only one Dao

```
public interface TransactionManager {
    <T> T executeTransaction(TransactionCode<T> code);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface TransactionCode<T> extends Function<MyDAO, T> {
}

public class ServiceLayer {

    private TransactionManager transactionManager;

    public ServiceLayer(TransactionManager manager) {
        transactionManager = manager;
    }

    public void doSomethingInTransaction() {
        transactionManager.executeTransaction((myDao) -> {
            myDao.doSomething();
            return null;
        });
    }
}

public class TransactionManagerMysql implements TransactionManager {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public TransactionManagerMysql(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T executeTransaction(TransactionCode<T> code) {
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            T result = code.apply(new MyDaoSQL(entityManager));
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sure I had to extend `Function` to a custom `N-Function` in order to be able to pass multiple input parameters (because this is how my teacher explained it). Well, I found out that I don't need to use `Function`, not even in the single-input scenario. Here the only purpose of extending `Function` is to invoke its method `apply()` from `ServiceLayer`. Instead of generalising to an `N-Function` I can just define a method with an adeguate number of inputs. To answer my question is enough to rewrite `TransactionCode` as follows:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TransactionCode<T> {

    T apply(MyDaoA daoA, MyDaoB daoB, MyDaoC daoC, MyDaoD daoD);

}
```